# What does 'tape' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> HP TouchPad vs. iPad vs. Xoom vs. PlayBook: the tale of the tape.

Comment: Where is it from?  Could do with some context on that.

Comment: it's a news title from a famous tech blog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *tale of the tape* is a term from the sport of boxing, which uses it to refer to a boxer's size and, more important, reach. http://www.allwords.com/word-tale+of+the+tape.html

Comment: As a native speaker, do you understand it without searching the dictinary ? just want to know how common.

Comment: Yes. Most Americans probably get this pretty easily, but one would probably have to be familiar with sports terms to understand it in more than a general way.

Comment: Born and raised in America, and have *never* heard this expression (until now, that is). Without an explanation, I would have tried to interpret "tape" as in "recording".

Comment: Reading and being heavily into UK/US idioms for 35 years, I have never heard this before. But then again I do not like boxing and have not seen the Rocky films where I guess I would have encountered this term. Another reason to be on ESC :)

Comment: I thought I was pretty familiar with sports terms.  Except for boxing terms.  And I'm seen the Rocky films (in a cursory way), but dubbed in German only.  And I'd not heard this term before.

Comment: @Martha: Yep. Which is why I said you have to have watched boxing matches, especially the pre-fight parts.

Comment: Never heard this in BE

Comment: I would have guessed it was referring to the finish line of a foot race, where there is traditionally a ribbon ("tape") strung across the finish line at chest height and the winner is the one to break the ribbon or break the tape. Once boxing was mentioned, I would have assumed it was referring to chest and bicep diameter, which could indicate strength.

Comment: I would have got the same implication as @Wayne here (British English), though I know the phrase.  I'd generically interpreted it as "which one of these will win" rather than "let's measure them all up".

Comment: The "tale of the tape" is not about who will win, it is merely comparing stats.  In boxing, where it originated, it would include the boxer's height, weight and reach (arm length).  In this article I would expect it to contain things like processing power, screen size/resolution, cost, etc.

Answer (score 5):

*The tale of the tape* means *comparing things*; it comes from boxing where the fighters would be measured with a tape measure before a fight.